# Why not add element in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Code:

```
$(function(){
    var Name = [];

    for($i=1; $i<16; $i++) {
        var id = $i;
        $.post("./index.php", {
            record : id
        }, function(data){
              Name.push(data);
        });
    }

    alert(Name);
});
```

data return result as `<a href="#"><img src="./name.jpg"></a>`

Tell me please why data not add in array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `post request` is an **async method** .

You will hit the alert even before you hit the success function.

```
    Asynchronous means that the script will send a request to the
 server, and continue its execution without waiting for the reply.
```

Comment: @Sushanth_-- thanks, tell me please how update code that alert show than will be give result all post?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing async operations (AJAX calls), your data will be updated **only after** the requests have completed. So, you should check your array after the ajax calls are done.
With the methods of [jQuery deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), this can be easily achieved as such :

```
$(function(){
    var Name = [];
    var requests = [];

    for($i=1; $i<16; $i++) {
        var id = $i;
        requests.push($.post("./index.php", {
            record : id
        }, function(data){
              Name.push(data);
        }));
    }

     $.when.apply($,requests).done(function(){
         alert(Name);
     });
});
```

Comment: nice) big thanks for my new knowledge)

Comment: @LeoLoki: with no means to offend you, I suggest you read articles about ajax to understand what is going on out there before asking question on SO.

Comment: thank you, I understand your motives, but I had to decide this today.

Comment: @gion-13 ERRORS: every time I get different arrays ! **[here all code and results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582144/why-do-i-get-a-different-array)**