# Why do I get a different array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.
I have  problem with give different arrays;

my code next:

```
setInterval(function() {

var TestName = [];
var requests = [];
TestName.push('0');
for($i=1; $i<8; $i++) {
    var id = $i;
    requests.push($.post("./Scripts/", {
    record:id,
    opt:'get_test'
    }, function(data){
          TestName.push(data);
    }));
}

 $.when.apply($,requests).done(function(){

     for($i=1; $i<8; $i++) {
$('#test'+$i).html('').html(TestName[$i]);

}
alert(TestName);
 });

}, 15000);
```

This code works but every time I get different arrays...

For example:

`alert(TestName);` **result one:**

```
0,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test1.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test2.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test3.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test4.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test5.png"></a>,
<a href="TestTestTestTestTest.php"><img src="./1358997710.jpg"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test7.png"></a>,
```

`alert(TestName);` **result two:**

```
0,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test1.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test2.png"></a>,
<a href="TestTestTestTestTest.php"><img src="./1358997710.jpg"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test3.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test5.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test4.png"></a>,
<a href="#"><img src="./images/test7.png"></a>
```

As you can see elements of the array each time exchange seats, and sometimes elements of the array are arranged in the wrong order.

Tell me please where may be been error in code?

Comment: just curious... why `$i` vs. the standard `i`?

Comment: @scunliffe I must admit I often name my variables with a preceding $, no idea why I do it, habbit from PHP probably.

Comment: ah yeah ok... I was just thinking I bet there's some PHP influence here.

Comment: remained habit from php)

Comment: @scunliffe  you was right)

Comment: is possible to check getting data from a previous request? For example, if the data were obtained and stored in an array, perform the following query. Or how can I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your array is different each time is that you are running asynchronous requests and then populating from the callback.  Each time you do this your requests happen to be finishing in different order and therefore populating the array in a different order.

You must not rely on async request callbacks being called at any particular point within your execution, they can be called at any time, depending on when the response decides to come back.

Comment: @Jon_Taylor is possible to check getting data from a previous request? For example, if the data were obtained and stored in an array, perform the following query. Or how can I do differently?

Comment: well just check if the array has been populated and if not do the query, or you could have an init method which does the async stuff and in its callback then carries on to use the data.