# Is it possible to conclude the code in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 25 elements on this page:

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<div id="test3"></div>
<div id="test4"></div>
<div id="test5"></div>
```

Also I have code for update html in divs:

```
setInterval(function() {

  $.post("./main/", {
    record:1,
    opt:'get_res'
  }, function(data){
    $test1=data;
  });

}, 15000);
```

To change the html in all the blocks I need to run this code 5 times, ex:

```
setInterval(function() {

  $.post("./main/", {
    record:1,
    opt:'get_res'
  }, function(data){
    $test1=data;
  });

}, 15000);

setInterval(function() {

  $.post("./main/", {
    record:2,
    opt:'get_res'
  }, function(data){
    $test2=data;
  });

}, 15000);

.....
.....

setInterval(function() {

  $.post("./main/", {
    record:3,
    opt:'get_res'
  }, function(data){
    $test3=data;
  });

}, 15000);
```

For example for 25 elements div need write this code 25 times - it will be been very big code.

Tell me please whether implementation of the code in a loop, so as not to repeat it several times?

Comment: It would be more efficient if you could just one `$.post` and use that to "feed" your elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over the elements somehow, use the index or extract the number from the ID, and store in an array or object, whatever fits best :

```
var test = {};
setInterval(function() {
    $('div[id^="test"]').each(function(i, ele) {
        (function(idx) {
            $.post("./main/", {
                record: idx,
                opt:'get_res'
            }, function(data){
                test[idx] = data;
            });
        })(i+1);
    });
}, 15000);
```

Comment: and how make next step? see **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582144/why-do-i-get-a-different-array)**. i have errors when want use arrays....

Comment: @LeoLoki - you solve that with a closure, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

you should look at http://api.jquery.com/each/ function:

**Update**: basically you can use any selector to find your elements

Suppose you have a simple unordered list on the page:

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li class="findMe">foo2</li>
    <li class="findMe">bar2</li>
</ul>
```

You can select the list items and iterate across them:

```
$( ".findMe" ).each(function( index ) {
  //do something ... post or anything else
});
```

Comment: @Shlomi_Schwartz but your code find all div on page and how use him with `.post` ?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is you can make test as array ans use this code

```
 for (i = 1 , i<=25 , i++)
  $.post("./main/", {
  record:i,
  opt:'get_res'
  }, function(data){
  $test[i]=data;
  });

  }, 15000);
```